# How to copy to clipboard and change tooltips at the same time with JS

Tags: javascript, tooltip

I want to click to copy numbers to the clipboard and change the tooltip text from "Copy to clipboard" to "Copied: [number]" when clicked.

With many numbers, I don't want to use IDs to reduce my code.

I have managed to copy numbers to the clipboard but I am struggling with tooltips.

Any help or hint would be appreciated.

```js
const tds = document.querySelectorAll(".number");

tds.forEach(td => {
  td.onclick = function () {
    document.execCommand("copy");
  }

  td.addEventListener("copy", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.clipboardData) {
      event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", td.textContent);
      console.log(event.clipboardData.getData("text"));
      //the below 2 lines doesn't work
      var tooltip = document.getElementsByClassName("tooltiptext");
      tooltip.innerHTML = "copied" + event.clipboardData.getData("text");
    }
  });
})

function outFunc() {
  var tooltip = document.getElementsByClassName("tooltiptext");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copy to clipboard";
}
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position        : relative;
  display         : inline-block;
  }
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility      : hidden;
  width           : 140px;
  background-color: #555;
  color           : #fff;
  text-align      : center;
  border-radius   : 6px;
  padding         : 5px;
  position        : absolute;
  z-index         : 1;
  bottom          : 150%;
  left            : 50%;
  margin-left     : -75px;
  opacity         : 0;
  transition      : opacity 0.3s;
  }
.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content         : "";
  position        : absolute;
  top             : 100%;
  left            : 50%;
  margin-left     : -5px;
  border-width    : 5px;
  border-style    : solid;
  border-color    : #555 transparent transparent transparent;
  }
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility      : visible;
  opacity         : 1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">
  <span class="tooltiptext">Copy to clipboard</span>
  <a style="font-size: 2em;" onmouseout="outFunc()" class="number">1</a>
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
  <span class="tooltiptext">Copy to clipboard</span>
  <a style="font-size: 2em;" onmouseout="outFunc()" class="number">2</a>
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
  <span class="tooltiptext">Copy to clipboard</span>
  <a style="font-size: 2em;" onmouseout="outFunc()" class="number">3</a>
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
  <span class="tooltiptext">Copy to clipboard</span>
  <a style="font-size: 2em;" onmouseout="outFunc()" class="number">4</a>
</div>
```

Comment: your HTML is wrong, you have  some links inside a links.

Comment: @Mister Jojo thanks for the reply. You mean a tags inside a tags? I deleted them for you. Can you help me now?

Comment: I mean you can't have a tag `<a..>` (== Link) inside an other one, it's a basic HTML rule. And I don't understand why you're using links elements without the need of indicate their `href` property... there no logic in your HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. No, there is no logic you are looking for. I just want people to click to copy the text to the clipboard. And I want to let people know the text is copied with tooltips. I didn't matter whether the tag is  <a> or <label> etc.

Comment: @Lee, just post an answer. Check if it works

Comment: @James, thank you so much for your kind answer and explanation. I know I should have used something to specify which span (tooltip) to use. That would make my day easier. But I didn't want to do that because of a couple of reasons.

Unfortunately, the tooltips not changing messages properly with your solution.

Comment: @Lee, no problem , I could fix it, so you want it to have four spans and that is the only thing you want my code to change, right?

Comment: @Lee, Updated the code., check if it works. Also, your copy message currently will not working because you set `bottom: 150%` and `opacity:0`. Check if it works

Comment: OMG you are my savior! It works great. I hate to bug you but one thing is all tooltips are changed. I mean even when I mouse-over on the other numbers. I want the tooltip to be "copy to paste" when I move on to the other numbers.

Comment: @James I forgot to say THANK YOU! You've done more than enough for me.

Comment: @Lee no problem at all, just update the code but I have to mention that your code probably want to make the message hide at normal time (mouseenter), so you have to set in and it is too big which let user may not able to hover/click it. You have to restyle it.

Comment: @James Thank you very much!! Everything is as clear as I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This biggest problem is you doesn't specify the `[]` for `document.getElementsByClassName`.
.

There is one problem that you have noticed: It won't display the copy information correctly if you copy the two number or more at the same time because you assign the copy function to each individual `<span>`

Updated: I change the document.getElementsByClassName to `document.querySelectorAll` in order to use forEach, but if you don't want to, just use a for loop.

Also, your copy message currently will not working because you set `bottom: 150%` and `opacity:0

You should use `mouseenter`.

```js
const tds = document.querySelectorAll(".number");


document.querySelectorAll(".tooltiptext").forEach(link =>{
link.addEventListener('mouseenter',function(){
link.textContent = 'Copy and paste'
})
})
tds.forEach(td => {
  td.onclick = function () {
    document.execCommand("copy");
  }

  td.addEventListener("copy", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.clipboardData) {
      event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", td.textContent);
      console.log(event.clipboardData.getData("text"));
      //the below 2 lines doesn't work
      var tooltip = document.querySelectorAll(".tooltiptext");
      tooltip.forEach(item =>{
        item.innerHTML = "copied" + event.clipboardData.getData("text");
      })
    }
  });
})

function outFunc() {
  var tooltip = document.querySelectorAll(".tooltiptext");
      tooltip.forEach(item =>{
        item.innerHTML = "Copy to clipboard";
      })
}
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position        : relative;
  display         : inline-block;
  }
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  
  width           : 140px;
  background-color: #555;
  color           : #fff;
  text-align      : center;
  border-radius   : 6px;
  padding         : 5px;
  position        : absolute;
  z-index         : 1;
  left            : 50%;
  margin-left     : -75px;
  transition      : opacity 0.3s;
  }
.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content         : "";
  position        : absolute;
  top             : 100%;
  left            : 50%;
  margin-left     : -5px;
  border-width    : 5px;
  border-style    : solid;
  border-color    : #555 transparent transparent transparent;
  }
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility      : visible;
  opacity         : 1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">
  <span class="tooltiptext">Copy to clipboard</span>
  <a style="font-size: 2em;" onmouseout="outFunc()" class="number">1</a>
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
  <span class="tooltiptext">Copy to clipboard</span>
  <a style="font-size: 2em;" onmouseout="outFunc()" class="number">2</a>
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
  <span class="tooltiptext">Copy to clipboard</span>
  <a style="font-size: 2em;" onmouseout="outFunc()" class="number">3</a>
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
  <span class="tooltiptext">Copy to clipboard</span>
  <a style="font-size: 2em;" onmouseout="outFunc()" class="number">4</a>
</div>
```